# My hosting provider ask me to use xCache instead of the built in Drupal cache system

Tags: 7, performance

Just that I have a problem with a website (Drupal 7), the server falls down every night. 
My hosting provider ask me use xCache instead of built in Drupal cache system.
Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes perfect sense to use ***PHP opcode cache***, you should be using one if not already using. I'd recommend **APC** for PHP version 5.4 and less.

**xCache** is somewhat similar in the way it handles caching like APC, but the mechanism is different. You have to do quick research which one suits your needs and hosting compatibility.

If you are using PHP 5.5+ then it comes with in-house **OPcache**. Personally I haven't tested but when the package is bundled with software core it certainly grabs attention. You should check the use case for you.

**eAccelerator** is also nice one, I used to use it few years ago, but, when I got to play with more RAM, **APC** is beast.

The later part of your question says about

> use xCache instead of built in Drupal cache system

which is completely false, **xCache** or any other **opcode cache** is not replacement of **Drupal Cache**, it should be used together. Opcode cache is for PHP, it doesn't have anything to do with Drupal.

As for the part of replacement concerns, you can use **Memcached** instead of Drupal cache that is stored in database.

Comment: ok, I see. I've checked I have xcache version 1.3.0 install in my server. How do I do to activate it for my site? Is there any line I should add to sites/default/setting.php ?

Comment: In that case, look at Cache router https://drupal.org/project/cacherouter

Comment: drupal.org/project/cacherouter is for Drupal 6. I need it for drupal 7

Comment: you should have specified that in question or as tag

Comment: sorry I just forgot. I added it like a tag.

Comment: It'd be better for you to use xCache admin. If its not installed in your system then you can install it via http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/InstallAdministration. It gives you clear picture what is being served via xCache and those cache admin things...